# Запуск Python приложения после срабатывания UPDATE Trigger SQL Server 2014

Tags: python, sql-server

Задача состоит в следующем, мне нужно при обновлении поля в базе данных "сообщить" об этом в приложение на python. Работа с SQL для меня новая, возможно что-то упускаю.

В базе данных уже был готовый trigger в нужной мне таблице. Я пробовал по всякому добавлять туда Exec xp_cmdshell но это приводило к зависанию приложения которое вносит изменения в базу данных. При этом в диспетчере задач видно что Python приложение запущенно, но оно не открывается.

С нескольких попыток удается завершить процесс Python и основное приложение сообщает об ошибке "Создатель ошибки не указал причину". Прошу вашей помощи.

```
USE [RusGuardDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[OnEmployeePhotoUpdate]    Script Date: 30.04.2021 16:44:07 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[OnEmployeePhotoUpdate]
ON  [dbo].[EmployeePhoto]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

update EmployeePhoto
set ModificationDateTime = GETDATE()
where _id in (select _id from inserted)
--DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)
--SET @CMDSQL = 'cmd.exe /C "D:\untitled\test.bat"'
Exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\Users\IT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pythonw.exe D:\untitled\1.pyw'

END
```

Так же пробовал вставлять EXEC после END.

Comment: Вы уверены, что у учетной записи, под которой запущен SQL Server, есть доступ к C:\Users\IT\?

Comment: Нет. Эта учётная запись базы данных на сервере